# Weird Camera Iris Shutter Animation

Tags: ios, ipad, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm seeing a weird animation of the camera iris when I present a `UIImagePickerController` in a `UIPopoverController` with the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[popover setContentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

I should also mention that the `UIPopoverController` is already presented with another content view controller at this point and thus the call to `setContentViewController` is changing the popover's content to the image picker.

This is what is looks like when the image picker is shown:
[image: weird iris shutter animation]

What is going on here?

Comment: Do you get the same effect with `animated:NO`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of stewing over this, I came up with the solution!

The unsightly black bar below the shutter animation has to do with the fact that the `UIPopoverController` has a `UINavigationController` as it's content view controller before  setting the `UIImagePickerController` as the content view controller. The height of the black bar is the same height as the navigation bar of the `UINavigationController`.

Anyways, the solution was to set the popover content size to `[imagePicker contentSizeForViewInPopover]` before I set the `UIPopoverController's` content view controller to the `UIImagePickerController`.

Here's some code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[popover setPopoverContentSize:[imagePicker contentSizeForViewInPopover] animated:YES]
[popover setContentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

The key is this call right here:

```
[popover setPopoverContentSize:[imagePicker contentSizeForViewInPopover] animated:YES]
```